# Any cautions on importing a course from Moodle 3.4 via LTI to Blackboard?

Tags: moodle, blackboard, lti

We have this scenario working on moodle-to-moodle-via-LTI. Having no experience with Blackboard, we would appreciate it if anyone that tried this already can point us to some information on things to watch out for.
Thx

Comment: Are you only provisioning the course or are you bringing across content as well. If so what types?
Anecdotal as it is: I have had issues with Moodle Quiz types do not copy well, especially Cloze and Fill in the table type questions.

Comment: We are embedding a custom course (in this case, a Unity3D based game) and returning a completion flag and a grade.